# Как сохранить файл при сериализации?

Tags: android, сериализация

Здравствуйте, я только знакомлюсь с android studio, и у меня возникла проблема с сериализацией объекта. В джаве мне с данным вопросом всё более менее понятно, но с андройдом возникли следующие трудности:
Как создать папку в корневом каталоге на телефоне, и создать там фаил куда я буду сохранять свой объект?
Как сделать проверку есть ли такая папка и фаил? В джаве я для этой цели использовал класс Files и класс Path. Но здесь почему то команда Paths.get() подчеркивает get и требует 26 версию API. 
Ну или хотя бы подскажите функцию возвращающую путь к корневой папке на телефоне(не sdCard).
Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, рекомендую ознакомиться с [официальной документацией](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html).

Для работы с внутренней памятью есть метод `getFilesDir()`:

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
```

Проверка на существование:

```
file.exists();
```